# NGINX: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php

Im running CentOS 6.5 and just moved from apache to nginx. Im running wordpress website on the server with few plugins that use **scrapers** to get information from other websites, to be exact 2 **scrapers** , so I have to 2 cron jobs that doing it every 1h. The thing is when I moved to nginx I can run only one **scraper** at a time. When I try to run second one it just stops and I get error in logs **upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream**

I think it related to allowed php processes, but cant find the right setting for it. It would be cool if you can suggest what I need add/change to make it work.

fastcgi_connection_timeout  - wont work for me, because I need to run them at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:  `fastcgi_read_timeout 300;` in the server block and `proxy_read_timeout 300;` in the http block

Comment: I had the plugin and theme update problems with my local Wordpress installations that run on Laravel Valet with Nginx and putting these values in the right places actually solved my problem.